# How to calculate codon usage bias (RSCU) in biopython

Tags: python-2.7, bioinformatics, biopython

I'm looking to calculate the RSCU values for a given sequence using the module CodonUsage. In the source code for CodonUsage ([here](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqUtils.CodonUsage-pysrc.html)) RSCU values are calculated inside the function generate_index, which sits inside the class CodonAdaptionIndex (RSCU calculated at line 101). How do I access generate_index? Also, how do i get my script to access my sequences (so far they are in FASTA format on a .txt).

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the function by importing it like this and generating a CodonAdaptionIndex object:

```
from Bio.SeqUtils import CodonUsage as CU

myIndex = CU.CodonAdaptationIndex()
myIndex.generate_index("/path/to/myFastaFile")
```

From the documentation it looks like a FASTA formated file is perfectly fine to use.

Comment: Thanks! This appears to be working as far as i can tell. Do you know how to retrieve the output?

Comment: @ZoeYiasemides The result should be stored in `myIndex.index` and you can print it with `myIndex.print_index()`

Comment: What you get from this method is *NOT* the RSCU values, but the "relative adaptiveness", which is kinda a normalized RSCU values (see Sharp 1987 NAR paper).

Answer (score 3):

For Python 3+, try the [CAI](https://GitHub.com/Benjamin-Lee/CAI) package, which includes an [RSCU](https://cai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#CAI.RSCU) function that can handle alternate genetic codes:

```
from CAI import RSCU

RSCU("GATACAGTAGAC")
```